# Consequence of John and Nirenberg's lemma?

Tags: measure-theory, harmonic-analysis, elliptic-pde, regularity

The lemma I'm referring to in the title is the following:

**John and Nirenberg's lemma**: Let $C_0 \subset \mathbf{R}^n$ a finite cube. Let $u \in L^1(C_0)$ and assume there exists a constant $k$ such that for every subcube $C \subset C_0$ with parallel sides:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{|C|}\int_C |u\ -\ u_C| \le k
\end{equation}
Where $u_C$ is the average of $u$ over the cube $C$. Let $S_\sigma \ =\ \{\ x \in C_0:\ |u(x)\ -\ u_{C_0}| > \sigma \}$. Then
\begin{equation}
m(S_\sigma) \le \left( \frac{A}{k}\int_{C_0} |u\ -\ u_{C_0}| \right) e^{\frac{-\alpha \sigma}{k}}\ \text{for}\ \frac{\sigma}{k}\ge a
\end{equation}
Where $A \le 1$, $\alpha$ and $a$ are positive constants which depend only on $n$.

I would like to know if the following consequence is true.

**Consequence** If $u$ and $C_0$ are as above, then there exists a constant $M\ =\ M(n, C_0, k)$ such that:
\begin{equation}
\int_{C_0} e^{\alpha u}\ \int_{C_0} e^{-\alpha u} \le M
\end{equation}
*Proof:* We calculate using the above stated lemma
\begin{equation}
\int_{C_0} e^{\alpha |u\ -\ u_{C_0}|}\ =\ \int_{0}^{\infty} m(e^{\alpha |u\ -\ u_{C_0}|} \ge t ) dt\ =\ \int_{0}^{\infty} m(|u\ -\ u_{C_0}| \ge \frac{1}{\alpha} \log(t) ) dt\ \le \int_{0}^{e^{\alpha k a}} |C_0| dt\ +\ \int_{e^{\alpha k a}}^{\infty} \frac{A}{k} \left( \int_{C_0} |u\ -\ u_{C_0}|dx \right) e^{\frac{-\alpha t}{k}} dt\ \le\ e^{\alpha k a} |C_0|\ +\ \frac{A}{k}|C_0|k\ \int_{e^{\alpha k a}}^{\infty} e^{\frac{-\alpha t}{k}} dt\ =\ e^{\alpha k a} |C_0|\ +\ A|C_0|\frac{k}{\alpha}e^{-\frac{\alpha}{k}e^{\alpha k a}}\ :=\ \sqrt{M}
\end{equation}
We observe now that:
\begin{equation}
e^{\alpha (u\ -\ u_{C_0})}, e^{-\alpha (u\ -\ u_{C_0})} \le e^{\alpha |u\ -\ u_{C_0}|}
\end{equation}
So that:
\begin{equation}
\int_{C_0} e^{\alpha (u\ -\ u_{C_0})}\ \int_{C_0} e^{-\alpha (u\ -\ u_{C_0})}\ \le M
\end{equation}
And this concludes the proof.

Comment: Your "proof" is incorrect ($\sigma = \alpha^{-1} \log t$, not $\sigma = t$ when applying the lemma). One gets $\int_{C_0} e^{\lambda |u - u_{C_0}|} < M(\lambda,n,C_0,k)$ for $\lambda < k^{-1} \alpha$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really tried hard in spotting the error and could not see this simple mistake! @js21